# How to add a new font to WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I want to use a specific font on a website. I don't want to use any type of plugin, and the font I want, I don't find it free to add through a link, so I have decided with the `@font-face` method

1 - I add the following code to the styles.css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: university-roman;
    src: url(https://myWebsite.com/wp-content/themes/my-Theme/fonts/university-roman.otf);
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

2 - I have created the fonts folder in the following path of my directories:

**`wp-content/themes/my-Theme/fonts/university-roman.otf`**

3 - I have added the css corresponding to the text where I want to add the new fonts:

```
.site-title-main {
font-family: "university-roman", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

But the text does not display the University fonts.

What am I doing wrong ?

How can I make the new fonts work?

I hope I have described the problem that I cannot solve.

Thank you

Comment: If you use inspect element and go into the console, are there errors relating to the fonts not being found?

Comment: Where does the folder 'my-Theme' come into it?

Comment: No , the console does not show errors MattHamer5 ,
and sorry @AHaworth , I have already corrected the question

Comment: Add commas to `"university-roman"` in `@font-face`. Also the URL says `my-Them` but I think you just added that for example code.  Try path instead of url in `src`. try `ttf` file for that font.

Comment: I have added the " commas " as you suggested, but it doesn't work , @MuhammadZohaid

Answer (score 1):

In your @font-face css declaration. An `e` is missing in your path `/my-Them/` should be `/my-Theme/` isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @CheShy , but that's just a typo when typing the path where my Sources are located. As you can see, I have already corrected that in the question.
Thanks for the interest